# Android: Clicking children individually within a GridView

Tags: android

This is in the initial Activity when my app starts up. The gridview contains six click able icons that i want to all go to different activities. I have aboslutely no problem starting up a new activity for another thing to do in my app. I created one activity just to work with initially, a 'contact us' form. I want only one of these icons to go to that activity, however i can't find a way to make it so the onItemClickListener callback registers individual clicks for each icon and launches the appropriate activity; currently, no matter which icon i click, they all go to the same activity. See below for my code:

```
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        {

             Intent myIntent = new Intent();
             myIntent.setClassName("com.beneast.main", "com.beneast.main.ContactUs");
             startActivity(myIntent);
            };
    });
```

I am a bit of a noob at doing this as you can plainly see, this app is getting developed as i learn more stuff. But thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the `int position` parameter in the `onitemClick` method. The position parameter is the position of the icon in the gridview which has been clicked. So i would use a switch-case statement for your need as follows:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){         
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)                  
{
   switch(position)
    {
    case 0:               
   Intent myIntent = new Intent();              
   myIntent.setClassName("com.beneast.main", "com.beneast.main.ContactUs");                 
   startActivity(myIntent);
   break;

  case 1:
      Intent myIntent = new Intent();              
      myIntent.setClassName(X, Y);
      startActivity(myIntent);
      break;
    }
 };     
});
```

You would continue this to cover all possible cases i.e. all icon positions in the gridview.